# Trying to get records from joined tables in wp

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to join my two tables here. I searched how it's done in WP and came up with the following code, but it doesn't retrieve records from my tables. What is wrong here?

```
 $tbl_name  = $wpdb->prefix."member_deposit";
 $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix."users";

 $results = $wpdb->get_results("select * from  $tbl_name  INNER JOIN $table_name ON users.ID = member_deposit.ID   WHERE member_deposit.approve = 'unapprove'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$tbl_name  = $wpdb->prefix."member_deposit";
$table_name  = $wpdb->prefix."users";

$results = $wpdb->get_results("select * from  $tbl_name  INNER JOIN $table_name 
ON $table_name.ID = member_deposit.ID   WHERE $tbl_name.approve = 
'unapprove'");
```